# Name Suffixes: Does Yaten (Sailor Star Healer) ever refer to Usagi (Sailor Moon) by her civilian name?

Tags: culture, japanese-language, sailor-moon

Would Yaten use "Tsukino-san" to indicate his emotional distance from her, or merely "Tsukino" to indicate his penchant to be rude?

Is there any episode in which Yaten Kou (Sailor Star Healer) either directly addresses Tsukino Usagi (Sailor Moon) by her civilian name or refers to her by name when talking to someone else?  I've been searching through all the episodes of Sailor Stars, the 5th season of the Sailor Moon anime, but I cannot find an example.   He clearly calls her "Sailor Moon" when she is in sailor soldier form, but what does he call her as his classmate at school?

Taiki Kou calls Usagi "Tsukino-san" in episode 185. Seiya Kou (Sailor Star Fighter) calls Usagi by the nickname "Odango," and she calls him simply "Seiya," but she calls Yaten "Yaten-kun" and Taiki "Taiki-san;" Taiki calls Mizuno Ami (Sailor Mercury) "Mizuno-kun;" and both Ami and Hino Rei (Sailor Mars) call Seiya "Seiya-kun."

Comment: Note that "san," "chan," "kun," and such are usually called "honorifics" in English.